# Помогите с python win10toast

Tags: python

Я хочу сделать так чтобы у меня уведомление справа снизу отображалось до тех пор пока я его сам не закрою.

Код:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast("Notification", "This is test notification.", duration=10)
```

Если написать duration=None то появляется ошибка: TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Я понимаю то что там можно указать duration=секунды но мне именно надо чтобы пока я сам не закрою уведомление то оно не пропадёт.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности, в заголовке должна быть суть вопроса, а не призывы к кому-нибудь/чему-нибудь.

Comment: попробуйте указать 0 секунд

Comment: оно сразу закрылось.

Comment: бы? Вы попробывали? Обычно если требуется указать бесконечность времени то используют 0 или -1 как notify-send в флаге --expire-time

Comment: Ну у меня оно закрылось. Ну а если -1 то ошибка неправильное число.

Comment: метод show_toast задедержка по времени проиисходить через time.sleep() модуля time.

Comment: Максиматьно возможное для вас, например 24 часв

Comment: Если вы уж так любите пользоваться нейронками, спросили бы у них(

Answer (score 0):

Никак не сделать. duration там [передается в time.sleep()](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/blob/9d52b73f1af6c60162cf09b99269c4f7b13cdb00/win10toast/__init__.py#L112) и после указанного количества секуд окно закрывается.